# Maven project design - sharing a common project

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven and I'm trying to convert a few projects to work on Maven and I'm not sure what is the correct way to structure them - here is what I have:

I have a common module - named `Common` and two different applications that have nothing in common a part from the fact they both depend on `Common`. Let's call them `A` and `B`.

The dependencies between `A`->`Common` and `B`->`Common` are both for runtime and for tests - meaning that `A`'s test classes require `Common`'s test classes.

I tried various combinations I could think of - but non of them produced what I want.
The strange thing is that my code compiles, but JUnits fail since the test classes from `Common` are not found in the classpath.

Should I add 2 profiles to the `Common` to create 2 artifacts and add 2 dependencies in `A` and `B` to both artifacts? (Is that possible?) 
Is there a correct way to do what I wanted? Should I restructure my code to fit Maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common maven pitfall. Test classes from an artifact aren't available when you depend on that artifact. It is actually reasonable: when you depend on `Common`, you depend on production classes (JAR file). Test classes are needed only for running tests and aren't even included in the final JAR.

Assuming your `Common` test classes contain some utility method needed for all `Common` tests, `A` and `B` tests, here is a suggested structure:

- `Common-test` - containing common utility test classes (not test cases!) in `/src/main/java` (!)
- `Common` depends on `Common-test` with `<scope>test</scope>`
- `A` and `B` depend on both `Common` (with default scope) and `Common-test` (with `test` scope)

[image: UML]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/59899186))</sub>

Comment: What did you use to make this diagram? Looks neat.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly this is the kind of architecture recommended by Sonatype (http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/). Is that correct? Would you say the answer provided by Alexander Pogrebnyak (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161433/357360) does not adhere the Maven modularization recommendation?

Comment: That's the best way of doing it. Don't use this `test-jar` approach since it may cause some problems.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz there is not UML diagram, Would you please attach the diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You could structure it like

- Common project
- A project
- B project

Now add CommonProject to `<dependency>` for `A` & `B`, that will make the commonproject available at compile time so build would go good,

If your A & B is or webapp archtype then you need to make sure that your dependencies are available in WEB-INF/lib so that it can get the dependencies at runtime

To make the dependencies available only at `test` time, you could use [`test` scope](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

Answer (score 2):

You have to run `test-jar` goal of `maven-jar-plugin` in your `Common` project.

This produces a new artifact with `tests` classifier, which contains all the classes and resources from `src/test` tree.

So, in Common add this:

```
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>test-jar</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

And in `A` and `B` add this

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>common.group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>Common</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note `<classifier>tests</classifier>` in this dependency declaration.

Comment: Thank you - that did the trick. But from what I read - this might not be the recommended architecture - is this correct? Is the answer provided by Tomasz Nurkiewicz (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11161411/357360) better from a maven architecture POV?

Comment: @RonK. I would say, if the resources `Common/src/test` contain back doors to create test object in `Common`, use my approach.  If classes there contain common test harnesses and frameworks use Tomasz' approach.